# mongodb listen changes on collection change nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to listen changes on mongodb collection in nodejs. So I tried

```
constructor(@InjectModel("Alert") private readonly alertModel: Model<Alert>) {
    this.startAlertBot();
}
```

and this is `startAlertBot`

```
startAlertBot(): void {
    console.log("Starting Bot");
    this.alertModel.watch().on("change", (data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
    });
}
```

but this was showing

```
MongoServerError: The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets
```

So using [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) i tried to up my local standalone server with replica set, this is the command

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath ../db_data/db0 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,127.0.0.1
```

but this is showing

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-27T13:04:01.478+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-27T13:04:02.279+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":1000}}
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running this command in cmd (Admin mode)

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/db0 --replSet rs0
```

the next step was to initiate replica set.

To initiate replica set need to install [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongosh) and after installtion this will provide you the shell on which you need to run this command

```
rs.initiate()
```

now on the first terminal that was showing next wakeup call messages will show that server has started now.